# how to get the index of an Option from its value

Tags: javascript

I know how to get the value of an Option from its index as shown below in the code section.

Is there a way to get the corresponding index by passing the text/value i.e 'white' or 'blue'

```
<select id="Color">
<option>white</option>
<option>blue</option>
</select>

var x = document.getElementById("Color").selectedIndex;
var y = document.getElementById("Color").options;
alert("Index: " + y[x].index + " is " + y[x].text);
```

Comment: There really is no way other than iterating over the set of options.

Comment: oops...i am disappointed to know that. nevertheless thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: but is there a function to know whether an element exists in an array or not ? array.prototype.find is an experimental one and not advised to use in production code. Is there any other way apart from iterating the whole array and checking on every iteration.

Comment: For checking if a DOM element exists in an array, using `querySelector()`/`querySelectorAll()` is a good practice. The latter will return a `Nodelist` which will be another array. An alternative would be to use `Node.contains(otherNode)` which will return a boolean value of whether the `otherNode` is a descendant of the former.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with jQuery.

```
function returnIndex(value) {
    var selected = $("option:contains(" + value + ")")[0];
    if (selected) {
        selected.selected = "true";
        return selected.index;
    } else {
        console.log("Value does not exist");
    }
}

var x = document.getElementById("Color").selectedIndex;
var y = document.getElementById("Color").options;
var chosen = document.getElementById("Color").value;
alert("Index: " + returnIndex(chosen) + " is " + y[x].text);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find index of an item in following way

```
var z = "blue";
var y = document.getElementById("Color").options;
var myArray = [];
for(var i=0;i<y.length;i++)
{
    myArray.push(y[i].text);
}
var elementPos = myArray.map(function(x) {return x; }).indexOf(z);
alert(elementPos);
```

Comment: yes , this is good way ...but the point is still i can't avoid iteration. anyways thanks a lot